# Oracle delete table is so slow

Tags: oracle, sql-delete

I use oracle database, there is a table named "LOG" which has 500 thousand rows. When I execute `delete from LOG` in SQL Developer it costs 42 seconds.

Comment: Do you have a question about that? You forgot to type it.

Comment: Is the table referenced by other tables? If not you can use `truncate` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're deleting about 10k records a second. If Oracle is also writing an audit record for each delete you've got an equivalent number of writes. If the table is indexed then the indexes are also being updated - more writes.

What time were you expecting and why?